# How do I log current user context out in firebase using Expo React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, authprovider

I'm building an iOS application in React Native using Expo, and I'm using firebase to handle user creation and login. I have an AuthProvider.js class that basically allows me to set a global state (logged in/logged out) throughout the application.

Here is the `AuthProvider.js`

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { auth } from '../frontend/screens/firebase'; // Import your Firebase auth instance here

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null); // Initialize user as null

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        setUser(authUser); // Set the user if authenticated
      } else {
        setUser(null); // Set user to null if not authenticated
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

Then in `App.js`, I've wrapped all my screens in this  tag.

This seems to work fine when I login, here is the `Login.js`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, Image } from 'react-native';
import { COLORS, assets } from '../constants';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { auth } from './firebase';

const Login = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        navigation.navigate('Home');
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const handleGoBack = () => {
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  const handleSignup = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Signup'); // Navigate to the login screen
  };

  const handleLogin = () => {
    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log('User logged in successfully:', user.email);
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error.message));
  };

  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={assets.demoLoginImage}
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: 'cover',
        height: '50%',
      }}
    >
      {/* Add a button in the top left corner with an icon */}
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleGoBack} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 50, left: 30, zIndex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.white, borderRadius: 20 }}>
        <Image source={assets.back} style={{ width: 12, height: 12, tintColor: COLORS.secondary, margin: 10 }} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          height: '65%',
          paddingHorizontal: 16,
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          backgroundColor: COLORS.primary,
          paddingTop: 20,
          borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
          borderTopRightRadius: 20,
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 24,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            marginBottom: 16,
            color: 'white',
            paddingTop: 5,
          }}
        >
          Log ind
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            padding: 12,
            marginTop: 20,
            marginBottom: 20,
            borderRadius: 8,
            width: '100%',
          }}
          placeholder="Email"
          keyboardType="email-address"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            padding: 12,
            marginBottom: 5,
            borderRadius: 8,
            width: '100%',
          }}
          placeholder="Password"
          secureTextEntry
          onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        />
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', width: '100%', marginBottom: 20 }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              color: 'white',
              fontSize: 14,
              marginTop: 5,
              marginBottom: 20,
            }}
          >
            Forgot Password?
          </Text>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={handleLogin}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: COLORS.secondary,
            padding: 16,
            borderRadius: 8,
            alignItems: 'center',
            width: '100%',
          }}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              color: 'white',
              fontSize: 18,
            }}
          >
            Log ind
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 20 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleFacebookLogin()}>
            <Image source={assets.facebook} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, marginRight: 10 }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleGoogleLogin()}>
            <Image source={assets.google} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end', marginBottom: 20 }}>
          {/* "Log ind" and the button */}
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 16 }}>Don't have an account? </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSignup}>
              <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline', color: COLORS.white, fontSize: 16 }}>Sign Up</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

However when I Logout, I keep getting different kind of errors. For example I've tried this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { auth } from '../screens/firebase';
import { useAuth } from '../../auth/AuthProvider'; // Import your AuthContext

const Profile = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { setUser } = useAuth();  // Get the setUser function from AuthContext

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      // Sign out the user using Firebase
      await auth.signOut();
      // Set user state to null
      setUser(null);
      // Navigate to a screen of your choice (e.g., Login)
      navigation.navigate('Login');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Logout error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View>
      <Text>Profile Screen</Text>
      {/* Add your profile content here */}
      <Button title="Logout" onPress={handleLogout} />
    </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

When I click on the logout button it does log out but I get these two errors:

> ERROR  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'setUser' of null]
> Logout error: [TypeError: setUser is not a function (it is undefined)]